# How to disable AppDynamics for debug build type

Tags: android, gradle, appdynamics

I have a android project using AppDynamics plugin version 24.1.0, configuration like this:

```
apply plugin: 'adeum'

buildTypes {
  debug {
  }

  release {
  }

  debugForA.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
  
  debugForA {
  }
}

adeum {
  disabledForBuildType = ["debug"]
}
```

I also have few flavors for some dimensions, then I run assemblexxxDebug, every time the DexArchiveBuilder Task's cache is broken by BuildInfo.class which appdynamics generated.

The BuildInfo.class have an field applicationBuildId that assigned to a random ID string, so the cache of Gradle task can not be reuse.

The log in appdynamics_eu_android_bci.log show sth like:

```
<Injector> Initializing ClassStreamRewriter.
<Injector> Intector version = f7e7dca12ee3ec8c0b9f68caf93bccde9cc916596
<Injector> Using config = InjectorCnofig{, xxxx
<BuildInfoInjector> Generating com/appdynamics/eumagent/runtime/BuildInfo to stroe build ids at runtime.
<BuildInfoInjector> Injected applicationBuildId = xxxxxxx
<BuildInfoInjector> Finished generating com/appdynamics/eumagent/runtime/BuildInfo
...
```

disabledForBuildType seems not worked, or something else I don't know how to disable generating the BuildInfo class with random applicatinBuilId.